# Accessing QueryString parameters in ItemAdding event

Tags: parameter

I am trying to access query string in ItemAdding event but no luck. I thought I can use HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString to pull query string but HttpContext.Current
object is null under Sandbox. I am aware of using Javascript and hidden field to get the query parameter but I am looking for server side implementation. Is there any workaround to pull query string parameters?

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties eventProperties)
{
    // throwing null exception for HttpContext.Current
    string accountDir = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["AccountDir"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the approach [of saving the value of HttpContext to a variable inside the constructor, and then using that variable in the event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601352/how-to-obtain-the-httpcontext-in-event-handler) would work?

I'm actually surprised to learn that you can get the HttpContext for -ing events in Farm solutions. I assume there still must be cases where it's null there, e.g. if items are added in a console application.

Comment: I will surely try this approach though I am bit scare using static variable in event receiver class. Is there any impact of using static context to other users?

Comment: I think the part with the static variable was to pass it into ItemAdded from ItemAdding, so probably not needed for you.